# Read from text file into char array[]

Tags: c, file

in my project I used arrays not pointers. My purpose is here copy all characters one-by-one from text.file into array. I found some examples from the Internet, this site but none of them was useful for me.
Think that input1.txt is "abcd" I want like these input1[0] = a, input1[1] = b, etc.

```
main ()
{
    FILE *f1 = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
    int i;
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END); 
    int inputsize = ftell(f1); //its about text's size
    char input1[inputsize];
    for(i = 0; i < inputsize; i++)
    {
          fscanf(f1, "%c", &input1[i]);
    }
    printf("%c ", input1[3]);
    getchar();
}
```

When I run this code it doesn't print "d", but prints "6". Why is this happening? What should I do? Thanks for help

Comment: Check what fopen returns

Comment: It returns pointer. Must I use pointer? but I made all project according to array. I can not change it. Today is due date. Is any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your own way is good. Note that ftell returns long int type not int type..

Answer (score 4):

You seek to the end of the file to obtain it's size, but don't seek back to the start of the file again before you start actually reading it.

Insert just before your loop:

```
fseek(f1,0,SEEK_SET);
```

Pasting your code into my compiler with this amendment worked on my machine

Comment: @user119949: Welcome to SO! Your status suggests you have not yet read [About Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Please do so at your convenience; it won't take too much of your time. Pay particular attention to the paragraph about *accepting an answer*.

Comment: Great don't forget to accept the answer if you want to thank :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a function rewind(FILE*) instead of doing an fseek() again.

Worth noting should be the fact that you're allocating an array with a variable, which might be a bad idea in this case (especially when you could be reading a bigger file than one with 4 characters).